# Reorganize data frame in R (sum probability)

Tags: r

How to transform df1 to df2?

df1 looks like:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Sample_Set=c(1,2,1,4),
              Frequency=c(1,2,1,3),
              Probability=c(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25))
```

df2:

```
df2 <- data.frame(Frequency=c(1,2,3),
              Sample1=c(0.5,0,0),
              Sample2=c(0,0.25,0),
              Sample3=c(0.00,0.00,0.00),
              Sample4=c(0,0,0.25))
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic that gets you from the first to the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We group by 'Frequency', `summarise` by taking the `sum` of 'Probability', and then reshape it to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`.  Inorder to get the whole combinations of 'Sample_Set' where some values are not available, we use `complete`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(Frequency) %>%
  summarise(Sample_Set = first(Sample_Set),
            Probability = sum(Probability)) %>%
  mutate(Sample_Set = str_c('Sample', Sample_Set)) %>%
  complete(Frequency, Sample_Set = str_c("Sample", 1:4),
         fill = list(Probability = 0)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Sample_Set, values_from = Probability, 
       values_fill = list(Probability = 0))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  Frequency Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Sample4
#      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1         1     0.5    0          0    0   
#2         2     0      0.25       0    0   
#3         3     0      0          0    0.25
```